# Questions on direction of dot product

Tags: vectors, physics

So i am having problems with understanding that if two forces (suppose in parallelogram law of addition of two vector) the resultant has the same direction as the diagonal between them. So theta (angle between resultant and the base vector) represents the direction of resultant by that cos theta shouldn't have hand in showing the direction. Am I right?
Second question is that in dot products how can the product of two vector be scalar? Because from the image as you can see the vector is moving in the forward direction, then how it is scalar?[image shows a body is pulled by a force f and cover displacement s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuuqJ.jpg)

Comment: The dot product is scalar in the sense that it is just a single real number. However, real numbers can be both positive and negative, so the some of the information about direction is retained. As for your other question, I would suggest explaining what your problem is in more detail, ideally with a concrete example where you get confused. Also a higher-quality image.

Comment: In the first part of your question, you seem to consider 4 distinct vectors: two force vectors, their resultant, and a "base vector". Please define them better, give them names, and state clearly what angle you are considering.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! Angle $\theta$ is the angle between the force vector $\vec{F}$ and the displacement vector (toward the moving direction) $\vec{r}$.

So the work done by the force is $W=\vec{F}\cdot \vec{r}$

The middle $\cdot$ is called the dot-product, and it is defined as:

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(\theta)$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vector, and $|\vec{a}|$ is the length of the vector $\vec{a}$. So the length is a non-negative number, and $\cos(\theta)$ is a number between $-1$ and $1$, so the dot-product gives a number, and we call it "scalar".

Now, go back to the work,
$$W=\vec{F}\cdot \vec{r}=|\vec{F}||\vec{r}|\cos(\theta)$$